# Select default terminal for Files > Open in Terminal

Tags: unity, gnome-terminal, default-programs, terminator

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver and have changed the default Terminal program which seems to have worked for all other instances where I need to open a Terminal but not when selecting **Files > Open in Terminal** - here it still opens the OLD style terminal.

Is there a way to make it use Terminator which is what I have selected for my default?